# Nothing to show for the past several months at work

Tags: career-development

I've been working in a job for a little over 18 months. The company is seriously small - for a long period I was the only full time employee, I work in a semi skilled position, requiring some knowledge of the industry but training was given.

For the first few months I was learning the position and a lot of training was given to help. Once I had learned the basics I started making more managerial decisions, eventually I assumed a position where I was managing most of the businesses functions/needs/tasks etc.

After I had been working nearly a year the owner made it quite clear he did not want me to leave, even though I had shown no interest in leaving. They said as long as I am here they would do what ever they can to help with my long term career goals i.e experience in a certain area, putting me on courses to help with qualifications etc.

However a few months later wasn't on any courses, the owner was showing less interest in the company as he had interests in other businesses and my daily activities at work were becoming more menial. I was finding myself in a position where I was working to just keep the company running rather than growing or exploring new areas.

I started looking for another job but the owner then said he would put more interest in the business and I would be given more advanced work. Another few months later nothing had changed, I was pushing new ideas to the owner and they we just getting ignored, for almost a month now I have had very little contact off of him, I am given very little work to do and when I make suggestions he disappears and doesn't make any contact for weeks. He has pretty much given up on this business and doesn't show an interest in it at all.

I am now looking for a new job but I am concerned what I can say interviewers. If they ask what my current job involves I can only say menial activities. If they ask for an example of when I have lead a project I can explain how I formulates ideas and produced reports on a given topic but they wasn't a success because they was ignored.

I feel now I am in a worse position than I was 6 months ago.

What is my best option in this situation?

Comment: The only way to really change your role is by changing companies.  If you stay there things are likely to just get more stagnant

Comment: From what you write, it is nor Clear whether you Took an active part in your career development or if you were relying on someone else to define your career path. It would help-to clarify this

Answer (score 6):

> What is my best option in this situation?

I'm not sure what you are looking for here, but let me give it a shot.

When looking for a new job, trying to show what makes you different from all the other candidates is usually a good thing.

Being the sole employee of a business puts you in a rather unique position. Learning enough to earn the owners trust is a good sign. Managing most of a businesses functions/needs/tasks sets you apart from others.

As you look for your next job, your best option is to reflect on all the positives of the last 18 months, find ways to use them to your advantage, and be positive about them in your resume and in interviews. If necessary, practice conveying that optimistic outlook during mock interviews with your friends.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Don't stick to what you were doing yesterday.  Speak broadly of what you've done over the course of the complete time at the company.  Even in a great company, people have lulls.

Speak of the parts of the job you liked - taking responsibility, managing business functions.  And skip the small stuff of late that hasn't been challenging.

They are hiring you for what you are capable of, not what you were doing yesterday.  Don't think of "current" as the absolute most recent experience - think of it as an option to talk about skills you have used on the job, and would be able employ quickly in a new job.

Answer (score 1):

When you first started this job, were all the tasks menial?  Something else to consider is what you call menial may not be menial to someone else as there is something to be said for what proficiency have you developed in this job?  Are you closing sales?  What is involved in managing things so that the owner can focus more on other businesses?  These are where I'd go as there is something to be said for working well on your own as that does appear to be the case here no?  While right now things are in one state, look back over all of what you've done rather than just in the past week or month.